# How can I stretch shell terminal (CLI) window to fill the entire screen on Ubuntu in VMWare?

Tags: command-line, screen, vmware, window

I am running Ubuntu in VMware and I want to see CLI/Terminal fill the entire screen (screen should not include a timestamp or anything, just CLI). Do we need any extra tool in Ubuntu to make the CLI fill the entire screen?

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific? Do you refer to a terminal emulator or a virtual console? And which screen do you mean? That of the host or the guest system? What's the current screen resolution of the two?

Answer (score 4):

In your terminal press <kbd>F11</kbd> to make your terminal full screen.

You can also switch to a tty using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd>, where <kbd>Fx</kbd> can be <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, ...